# Scrolling in Chrome (latest version) on iPad/iPhone blocks javascript execution

Tags: javascript, iphone, google-chrome, ipad

I have encounter a problem with Chrome that is similar to an older issue with Firefox at this URL: [Scrolling blocks javascript execution in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509613/scrolling-blocks-javascript-execution-in-firefox).

I used the jsfiddle example script that was provided in the other link above to verify the problem with Chrome (version 44.0.2403.67).

This issue is present on iPads and iPhones.

This can cause real clunky behavior in certain scenarios for Web applications like we are developing.

**Update**

Use Model

While the user scrolls, I have a timer in the background that periodically adds more items to the search list that he/she is viewing. This works fine for all supported OSs/Browsers/devices except for Chrome on iPad/iPhone devices

Does anyone know of a workaround?

Thanks...

Comment: Chrome is just a Safari WebView in iOS, and it's a native limitation of iOS that JavaScript will not be executed when scrolling. There is no way to get around it, though I think iOS 8 fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have tested Safari and it does work correctly. I was hoping for a workaround. Guess I will recommend Safari over Chrome to our iPad/iPhone customers and let the customer decide what is most important for them. I am testing on iOS 8.4.1, so this is still an issue.

Comment: Just some correction: For a UIWebView scrolling won't block JavaScript execution, instead it just [blocks the screen from redrawing](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/scroll-event-change-ios-8-big-deal/). Safari does not have this problem (iOS 8 or later).

Comment: If you check out the jsfiddle example in the other link, the counter stops and does not restart until the scrolling is terminated. I have repeatedly tested this on the iPad with the same result. The display does not update, but neither does the value. Once scrolling is stopped, the counter begins incrementing. I have the same issue with a timer in my application.

Comment: Probably because iOS hold off `setTimeout` callbacks.